# Interface with classes

Tags: java

I have not implemented interface methods in class B and implemented in class C and i typecasted that object to class B and its working,how ?`

```
interface A {

void m1();

}


class C implements A{

    public void m1(){}

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      C c=new C();

      //B b=(B)c; //compile time error incompatible types

      A a=c;

      B b1=(B)a; //no compile time error,why ?it is not 
   }

}

class B{}
```

Comment: i have class  C wch is not extending from class B and not implementing interface A  how it is type casted to class B